# Simpler stop-over option

Tags: indian-citizens, thailand, malaysia, stopovers

I have an Indian passport. I have an option of choosing Kuala Lumpur or Bangkok for layover, each 24 hours. Outbound I fly Hyderabad, India to Vientiane, Laos with return from Ho Chi Minh City. Flying either Thai Airways or AirAsia.

Will I need visa to go into the city and if so for which country would the procedure be simpler?

Comment: @pnuts : I have an onward trip from Hyderabad,India to Vientiane,Laos and a return trip from Ho Chi Minh city, Vietnam back to Hyderabad. I am considering using the transit to look around either Bangkok (during the return) /Kuala Lampur (during the onward trip). Airlines: Thai or AirAsia.

Answer (score 10):

UPDATE: From the two options either Bangkok or Kuala Lumpur, I think Bangkok is more feasible to enter easily for Indian nationals because there is no restrictions to enter Thailand. Howevere Kuala Lumpur (Malaysia) you have to have enter first Indonesia, Thailand or Singapore then Malaysian immigration would allow an entry at airport otherwise you need a proper visa (Malaysia) if you wanna travel Hyderabad to Kuala Lumpur

> Yes, Indian passport holders can avail VOA (Visa On Arrival) facility
>   for both Thailand and Kuala Lumpur. Howevere there are some conditiond which are different from each other. Below is all the required information available and Indian national must meet all the requirement to avail VOA/transit facility

National of Indian with normal passport holder holders travelling as a tourist can obtain visa on arrival VOA at any Thailand international airport  for a maximum of 15 days.

Source: [Visa And Passport](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=TH&DV=Thailand&h=2b5cedc4d493a441eb85c5664f26fbabb9bdc343)

> [image]

Also Nationals of India with a visa issued by Indonesia, Singapore and Thailand can obtain a visa on arrival Kuala Lumpur, Johar Bahru, Kota Kinabatu,Kuching and Penang for a maximum of 7 days.

**Conditions**: they must arrive directly from Indonesia, Singapore or Thailand. They must also have return/onward ticket and at least USD 1000/= per passenger.

Source: [Visa And Passport](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=MY&DV=Malaysia&h=e2a23512491be45781a7e382acc8caa8ced4f)

> [image]

Comment: Also Bangkok is a bit closer to both HYD and VTE than KUL.

Answer (score 6):

In both countries you will need a visa to enter.  And in both countries, as an citizen of India, you can apply for a Visa on Arrival at the airport.

The time it takes in either location is dependent on how many flights arrive from VOA countries around the time your flight arrives.  Could be just your flight and you are through in a half hour, could be several flights and you might need an hour or more.

The biggest differences are in costs and requirements.

Thailand's VOA for Indian citizens is 1000 baht (about US$30), Malaysia's is RM330 (about US$80).

Thailand requires travelers to have 10,000 baht (20,000 baht if family) or equivalent, Malaysia requires travelers to have US$1000.  Thailand will accept a mix of cash and credit cards, not sure about Malaysia's stance on that.

Both require onward tickets, but you obviously have that covered.

Thailand's VOA is valid for 15 days, Malaysia's for 7 day (but this is just trivia since your stay is only 24 hours).  Both expire when you leave, so you have the repeat the process if you layover on your way back.

Comment: @pnuts - As the OP mentions 24 hour layovers and Thai / Air Asia, it sounds like separate tickets and a likelihood that bags will not be checked through, so they would need to enter the country anyway to claim and recheck bags (assuming they are checking baggage).